# Find no es una funcion

Tags: jquery, nodejs

Estoy trabajando con node js y en el modelo me da este error

> TypeError: $.find is not a function

Utilizo jquery para hacer el find

```
models.Account.authenticate = function(login, password, cb){
  var hashpass = common.hash(password, 'user.salt');
  var $ = require('jquery');

  $.find({where: { username: login }}).success(function(acc) {
     //if (acc && acc.pass != password) acc = null;
      if (acc && acc.pass != hashpass) acc = null;
      if (cb) cb(acc);
  }).error(function(err){
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

A la funcion authenticate  se le llama desde el controller para comprobar si el usuario existe en la base de datos.

```
   // POST: /login

    app.post('/login', function(req, res){ homeloginPost(req, res, {'api':false}); });
    var homeloginPost = function (req, res, mode) {
      models.Account.authenticate( req.body.user, req.body.pass, function(userFound) {
        if (userFound) {
        common.log(util.format( 'loginPost %s mode: %j', req.body.user, mode));
          req.session.regenerate(function(err){
            req.session.user = userFound;
            if (mode.api) {
              res.send({ok:true, user:userFound.name}); //json
            } else {
              res.redirect(req.body.redir || '/');
            }
          }); //session.regenerate
        } else { //not userFound
        common.log(util.format( 'loginPost DENIED %s mode: %j', req.body.user, mode));
          common.sleep(4000, function(){
            if (mode.api) {
              res.send({ok:false, error:'Incorrect credentials'}); //json
            } else {
              req.flash('warn', 'Incorrect credentials');
              res.redirect('/login');
            }
          });
        }
      });
    };
```

Ya probe lanzando el comando de instalacion npm installer jquery y sigue dando el error.

No sé porque me dice que no es una función.

Comment: no se entiende para que quieres usar jQuery del lado del servidor.. si bien es posible, la idea de jQuery es procesar el DOM, quiza quieras usar algun tipo de base de datos o algo similar. ¿Puedes explicar que intentas hacer o donde intentas buscar? quiza asi sea mas facil ayudarte,

Comment: md lo que hago es mandar el usuario y contraseña al controller y en el modelo compruebo con el authenticate si existe dicho usuario en la base de datos mysl. Gracias

Comment: ¿Ya has probado esto antes, con éxito? ¿Estás seguro de que se puede usar "$.find()". No sé de node js, pero en jQuery no hay una función "jQuery.find"; tienes que usarla sobre un elemento.

Comment: ¿No es `npm install jquery`, en vez de `installer`? Además, la idea de usar jquery en el lado del servidor también me parece bastante extraña.

Answer (score 0):

Ya existe una función nativa en JavaScript para hacer find
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find tal vez podés probar con eso.